# airflow.models import Param ImportError: cannot import name 'Param'

Tags: airflow

I am getting error as below. What can i do to fix it?

```
airflow.models import Param ImportError: cannot import name 'Param'
```

> Airflow version: 2.0.0

**DAG:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Param
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

is_debug_param = "{{ params.is_debug }}"
seti_param = "{{ params.seti }}"


def my_main(is_debug: bool, seti: str):
    print(is_debug)
    print(seti)


with DAG(
        dag_id="my_main",
        description='my_main',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        params={
            "is_debug": Param(default=False, type="boolean", ),
            "seti": Param(default="FG", type="string", enum=["FG", "RX"]),
        },
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:
    task_my_main = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_my_main_main',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=my_main,
        op_kwargs={
            "is_debug": is_debug_param,
            "seti": seti_param,
        },
    )

    (
        task_my_main
    )
```

Comment: its available from version 2.2.0 as far as I understand (for sure not in 2.0.0)

Comment: see if this helps : https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/_api/airflow/models/dagparam/index.html

Comment: @ozs not sure if i understand that approach well, how may i use that in my code, can u post as an answer. Appreciate ozs

Comment: Params added in version 2.2.0 see PR : https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17100. if you are using airflow<2.2.0 then you can define it as native dict only : {"is_debug": False, "seti": "FG"} without the enum  capability

Comment: @ozs so u mean is to replace `params={
            "is_debug": Param(default=False, type="boolean", ),
            "seti": Param(default="FG", type="string", enum=["FG", "RX"]),
        }` into: `params={"is_debug": False, "seti": "FG"}` and remove `from airflow.models import Param` then it should work?

Comment: @ozs i have done as above and now getting: `render_template_as_native_obj=True
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'render_template_as_native_obj`

Comment: yes, just a simple dict. I guess "render_template_as_native_obj" its again a matter of airflow version. which mean every parameter will be a string when airflow reads it and you'll have to cast it. see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for airflow version 2.0.0 there is no Param module (the pr for this change inserted in version 2.2.0 - see [github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17100](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17100))

also "render_template_as_native_obj" is not supported, so you'll have to cast the parameters.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import ast 

is_debug_param = "{{ params.is_debug }}"
seti_param = "{{ params.seti }}"
lst_param = "{{ params.lst }}"


def my_main(is_debug, seti, lst):
    print(ast.literal_eval(is_debug)) # bool
    print(seti)
    print(ast.literal_eval(lst)) # list


with DAG(
        dag_id="my_main",
        description='my_main',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        params={
            "is_debug": False,
            "seti": "FG",
            "lst": ["a", "b"],
        },
) as dag:
    task_my_main = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_my_main_main',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=my_main,
        op_kwargs={
            "is_debug": is_debug_param,
            "seti": seti_param,
            "lst": lst_param,
        },
    )

    (
        task_my_main
    )
```

Comment: yes this works, nevertheless no matter what i put when manually running `dag` into `is_debug` it is always `False` when doing print (seti takes value). `{
    "is_debug": True,
    "seti": "aaa"
}`

Comment: I am not sure its related, try to remove the params and check. I saw (also in version 2.5.1) that once you have only one task not always airflow refresh fast but it ran (go to Browse->Dag runs and check if it actually ran)

Comment: it was becauese dag must be enabled ... Can u answer my recent comment?

Comment: its because the casting.bool('False') = True. use ast module and run ast.literal_eval("False"). that what the render_template_as_native_obj=True is solving in later versions

Comment: so what i need to change in code the `is_debug` value to be taken correctly? I tried also to put `"is_debug": "True"` but its still `False` at the end...

Comment: yes, I updated my answer to get the value with ast

Comment: that perfectly works ozs. One last thing if u do not mind - is there possibility to pass `list of string` values? If so how should i implement it in that code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Arie, update my answer with list param.

Comment: thx, one last question: instead of putting all arguments like that: `def my_main(is_debug, seti, lst):`, can i simply put there `def my_main(**kwargs):` will it still works?

Comment: @Arie, yes you can.

Comment: but in that case how can i read specific variable's value out of it, like that? : `mylist = ast.literal_eval(kwargs['lst'])`  , `myseti= kwargs['seti']` , `mybool= ast.literal_eval(kwargs['is_debug'])`

Comment: yes, exactly as you wrote (kwargs is a dict)

Comment: could u check this post plz? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538532/access-params-values-from-another-function#76538532

Comment: is_debug_param is Jinja Template  so you need to use it on a template field (like op_kwargs -  you can see in the operator what field are templated), so airflow would know to parse/replace it by its value. when you pass it to the function like in pythonoperator via op_kwargs then airflow change it to the value while running. the ast.literal_eval must run on the value (inside a task function) of is_debug key not the jinja template itself (on the dag).

Comment: @Arie, I answered there (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76538532/access-params-values-from-another-function#76538532). notice the different when you are in dag code (while airflow parse) and on running mode (task is running).