# Access params values from another functions and different task

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have following code which uses `params`. I want to create another functions called `anotherfunction` and  and `someotherfunction` which will also use `params` besides `my_main`. Mentioned functions will be just particular functions called from `my_main`. Moreover I would like to have `finalfunction` which should be as `task` called just after `my_main` is finished and only when there is no error. That `finalfunction` should be also able to read values from `params` defined in `my_main`. For now i am getting i got this error:

```
    params = context['params']\n"
 "KeyError: 'params'\n")
```

Full code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import ast 

is_debug_param = "{{ params.is_debug }}"
seti_param = "{{ params.seti }}"
lst_param = "{{ params.lst }}"


def my_main(**kwargs):
    print(ast.literal_eval(kwargs["is_debug"])) # bool
    print(ast.literal_eval(kwargs["lst"])) # list

    anotherfunction()
    someotherfunction()

def anotherfunction(names={}, **context):
    params = context['params']
    print(params['is_debug'])

def someotherfunction(names={}, **context):
    params = context['params']
    print(params['is_debug'])

def finalfunction(names={}, **context):
    params = context['params']
    print(params['is_debug'])

with DAG(
        dag_id="my_main",
        description='my_main',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        params={
            "is_debug": False,
            "lst": ["a", "b"],
        },
) as dag:
    task_my_main = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_my_main_main',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=my_main,
        op_kwargs={
            "is_debug": is_debug_param,
            "lst": lst_param,
        },
    )

    (
        task_my_main
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

context its actually a dict that contains task_instance and dag_run info while running the dag, in case of op_kwargs those keys are added to this dict.

so, you can from my_main that was called from a task to pass this kwargs that contains all context data, or create another PythonOperator same as task_my_main.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
import ast

is_debug_param = "{{ params.is_debug }}"
seti_param = "{{ params.seti }}"
lst_param = "{{ params.lst }}"


def my_main(**kwargs):
    print(ast.literal_eval(kwargs["is_debug"]))  # bool
    print(ast.literal_eval(kwargs["lst"]))  # list
    anotherfunction(**kwargs)
    someotherfunction(**kwargs)


def anotherfunction(names={}, **context):
    params = context['params']
    print(params['is_debug'])


def someotherfunction(names={}, **context):
    params = context['params']
    print(params['is_debug'])


def finalfunction(names={}, **context):
    params = context['params']
    print(params['is_debug'])


with DAG(
        dag_id="my_main",
        description='my_main',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 6, 8, 1, 0),
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        params={
            "is_debug": False,
            "lst": ["a", "b"],
        },
) as dag:
    task_my_main = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_my_main_main',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=my_main,
        op_kwargs={
            "is_debug": is_debug_param,
            "lst": lst_param,
        },
    )

    task_final = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_final',
        provide_context=True,
        python_callable=finalfunction,
    )

    (
            task_my_main >> task_final
    )
```

Comment: where exactly in code should i do this: `you need to attach it to PythonOperator in the python_callable` as its currently in dag on the bottom? Note that i will be having more functions that will need to use that `**context` like also in `someotherfunction` (see updated main post). Can u show in my code as an answer plz for both additional functions?

Comment: @Arie, how do you intend to call those functions ?

Comment: Let's say `someotherfunction` and `anotherfunction` will be called directly from `my_main` function (so they are not separated tasks) and `finalfunction` will be called once after `my_main` task is finished (only if without errors) as separated `task`. Could u be so kind and show in answer how may i achieve that? I updated main post

Comment: @Arie, update my answer with both cases and explanation

Comment: i also updated main post with explanation. Ok let me check what u wrote